# Django lookup tables and fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-database

Can I look around in a database with Django? I mean outputting a list of all tables, all fields in tables and all objects in a specific table?

I know how to build models and lookup objects, but can I lookup fields in a preexisting database? I have a bit experience with unmanaged django models, but if I should use those, then I have to create models for alle the tables and specify each field. I think it should be possible to just look around in a database without 'managing it'. At least there must be a existing project on github or such with the functionality? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want `manage.py inspectdb` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)** to execute statements like **[Show Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)**